# Как сделать текст из частиц в three.js с анимацией его появления?

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js

Какими средствами этого можно добиться? Необходимо ли сначала реализовать это в каком либо 3D редакторе, а потом экспортировать в three, либо же можно сделать штатными средствами библиотеки?

*Я новичок в вопросах 3D графики.*

Comment: https://threejs.org/examples/ ссылку видели ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPD:** Если нужно заполнить точками замкнутую буферную геометрию (не через проекции точек и треугольников, а в полноценном 3D), то [здесь](https://discourse.threejs.org/t/how-fill-a-loaded-stl-mesh-not-simple-shapes-like-cube-etc-with-random-particles-and-animate-with-this-geometry-bound-in-three-js/4702/6?u=prisoner849) есть функция для этого.

Можно реализовать в 3D редакторе наверное, а в некоторых несложных случаях можно обойтись и без него. Берем проекцию точки на плоскость `xy` и смотрим, попадает ли она в проекцию любого из треугольников геометрии на эту же плоскость:

```js
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
camera.position.set(0, 10, 20);
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
  antialias: true
});
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

var light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 2);
light.position.setScalar(100);
scene.add(light);

var textGeo = null;
var newGeo = null;
var textPoints = null;
var loader = new THREE.FontLoader();
loader.load('https://threejs.org/examples/fonts/droid/droid_serif_bold.typeface.json', function(response) {
  var font = response;
  setText(font);
  render();
});

function setText(font) {
  textGeo = new THREE.TextGeometry("ABC", {
    font: font,
    size: 4,
    height: 0.25,
    curveSegments: 1,
    bevelEnabled: false
  });
  textGeo.computeBoundingBox();
  textGeo.computeVertexNormals();
  textGeo.center();

  fillWithPoints(textGeo, 1000);

  textGeo.vertices.forEach(function(vertex) {
    vertex.startPoint = vertex.clone();
    vertex.direction = vertex.clone().normalize();
  })
  textPoints = new THREE.Points(textGeo, new THREE.PointsMaterial({
    color: 0x00ff00,
    size: 0.1
  }));
  scene.add(textPoints);
}

function fillWithPoints(geometry, pointNumber) {
  geometry.computeBoundingBox();
  for (var i = 0; i < pointNumber; i++) {
    setRandomPoint(geometry);
  }
}

function setRandomPoint(geometry) {
  var point = new THREE.Vector3(
    THREE.Math.randFloat(geometry.boundingBox.min.x, geometry.boundingBox.max.x),
    THREE.Math.randFloat(geometry.boundingBox.min.y, geometry.boundingBox.max.y),
    THREE.Math.randFloat(geometry.boundingBox.min.z, geometry.boundingBox.max.z)
  );
  //console.log(point);
  if (isPointInside(point, geometry)) {
    geometry.vertices.push(point);
  } else {
    setRandomPoint(geometry);
  }
}

var a = new THREE.Vector3();
var b = new THREE.Vector3();
var c = new THREE.Vector3();
var face = new THREE.Face3();

function isPointInside(point, geometry) {
  var retVal = false;
  for (var i = 0; i < geometry.faces.length; i++) {
    face = geometry.faces[i];
    a = geometry.vertices[face.a];
    b = geometry.vertices[face.b];
    c = geometry.vertices[face.c];
    //console.log(face, a, b, c);
    if (ptInTriangle(point, a, b, c)) {
      var retVal = true;
      break;
    }
  }
  return retVal;
}

function ptInTriangle(p, p0, p1, p2) {
  // credits: http://jsfiddle.net/PerroAZUL/zdaY8/1/
  var A = 1 / 2 * (-p1.y * p2.x + p0.y * (-p1.x + p2.x) + p0.x * (p1.y - p2.y) + p1.x * p2.y);
  var sign = A < 0 ? -1 : 1;
  var s = (p0.y * p2.x - p0.x * p2.y + (p2.y - p0.y) * p.x + (p0.x - p2.x) * p.y) * sign;
  var t = (p0.x * p1.y - p0.y * p1.x + (p0.y - p1.y) * p.x + (p1.x - p0.x) * p.y) * sign;

  return s > 0 && t > 0 && (s + t) < 2 * A * sign;
}


function render() {
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
  textGeo.vertices.forEach(function(vertex) {
    vertex.copy(vertex.startPoint).addScaledVector(vertex.direction, 5 + Math.sin(Date.now() * 0.001) * 5);
  });
  textGeo.verticesNeedUpdate = true;
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/94/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
```

Comment: @pepel_xD Чисто из любопытства: помогло или нет? :)

Comment: @ prisoner849 очень!!!! Я новичок в этом деле,  но понял что-бы делать такие штуки нужно изучить вопрос 3D графики в целом. Последнее время занимаюсь этим  + 3ds max походу нужно, но пробовал экспортировать .3ds файл в three.js пока неудачно.
Спасибо за урок.

Comment: @pepel_xD Да не за что:) По поводу моделирования: у нас еще есть www.clara.io (бесплатная, браузерная), сделано не без помощи Three.js.