# css анимация и three.js

Tags: javascript, css, three.js

На странице используется графика построенная с использованием three.js, пока графика строится хотел использовать прелоадер на css (крутилка, вертелка).
Однако когда начинают строиться геометрии, крутилка-вертелка останавливается (браузер просто перестает проигрывать css анимацию).
На three.js происходит что-то вроде того, что обсуждалось в этом вопросе:
[Как сделать текст из частиц в three.js с анимацией его появления?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/851383/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%86-%d0%b2-three-js-%d1%81-%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b5%d0%b9-%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%8f%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f)

Comment: придется создавать геометрию в веб воркерах, если там математика

Comment: @Stranger in the Q понял спасибо